# Adding a complex object to session storage fails in Asp.Net webforms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a legacy webforms application.  For some reason, adding a complex object to session storage fails while adding simple data type like string works fine.  This session is being added in asp:UpdatePanel.  any ideas???

I see the following error in Global.asax, Application_Error module.

```
'((System.Web.HttpApplication)sender).Session' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'
```

Comment: If you using in-memory session, then quite much anything can be shoved in. However, sql sessions? (which I do HIGH recommend). Well, you can shove in a datatable, but you CAN NOT for example shove in a datarow. The reason of course is that any object you shove into the session() must be a serializable object.  In general, even most custom classe(s) you make will save just fine. So in some cases, I build my own simple class, and put that given object inside. Even most custom classes I build can go into session, and I not even marked them as serializable - but must be serializable.

Comment: I save my Session State in State Server

Comment: You haven't included the full exception details in your question. You've only told us what type of exception was thrown. Please include the rest of the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complex objects need to implement ISerializable in order be able to go into the state server.

Comment: Decorating the class with [Serializable()] did the trick.